# Is there way to get anything in ajax success response with MVC action returning emptyresult()

Tags: ajax, asp.net-mvc, asp.net-mvc-4

i have a controller action e.g create() that returns emptyresult() in it after doing some back end work . i am calling my create() action through ajax . Now if the back-end work is successful i want to do something back in jquery in ajax success . How should i do that ?

```
public ActionResult Create(string id)
{
//does something
return new EmptyResult();
}
```

and i want to do something in my ajax success portion now

```
        $.ajax({
            type: "POST",
            url: "@Url.Action("Create", "controller")",
            data: "{Id:'" + id + "'}",
            contentType: "application/json; charset=utf-8",
            dataType: "json",
            async: false,
            cache: false,
            success: function (response) {
                alert();
                $("#getoptionSp").empty();
                $("#getoptionSp").append("<div>Pending<div>");
            },
            error: function () {

            }
        })
```

i want to change the front end with jquery .. how can i do this if action return empty result . i cant return view it will be messier for the code .

Answer (score 0, accepted):

well i got the answer while trying just return

```
return Json("",JsonRequestBehavior.AllowGet);
```

and we are good to go for the ajax success response .